# Iterating through GDAL

Tags: gdal

I don't have that much skill with GDAL. I have multiple rasters that I need to clip among other things. I've made the following code which works for a single raster, however I do not know how to integrate this into a loop.

`gdalwarp -overwrite -ot Int16 -of GTiff -tr 926.6254331383334 -926.625433139166 -tap -cutline GEOFT_COUNTRY.shp -cl GEOFT_COUNTRY -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata -999999999.0 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co Z LE VEL=9 gf_Day2009_001.tif OUTPUT . tif`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ideas/options. I have yet to try them, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

1. Use `subprocess.call()` to open a new instance to run what you have. With each pass through, update the raster path as well as saved output. If you are having problems with `f-strings` or are using python2.7, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663852/python-subprocess-command-with-quotes-and-variables).

For an example and check out [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274632/proper-use-of-python-subprocess-for-gdal).

```
import os
import subprocess

raster_path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/CLIPPED"

for i, raster in enumerate(os.listdir(raster_path)):
    image = os.path.join(raster_path, raster)

    subprocess.call(f'gdal_warp -overwrite -ot Int16 -of GTiff -tr 926.6254331383334 -926.625433139166 -tap -cutline GEOFT_COUNTRY.shp -cl GEOFT_COUNTRY -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata -999999999.0 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co Z LE VEL=9 {image} OUTPUT_{i}.tif')
```

2. Use `gdal.warp` in a python script. There are multiple questions on this. You can look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444752/gdal-warp-in-python-script) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348624/transforming-raster-with-gdal-warp). The best source of information is going to be the [docs](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html).

The subprocess method is probably easiest to use at first, but through my experience and findings, creating a quality function and learning how to incorporate library functions within a python script is better (option 2).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, fiz algumas alterações e funcionou bem.

Comment: @DaviLuca Please accept if it solved your problem